# What is wrong with {% block %}?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Console:

django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 6: 'blосk'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Basic.html

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>{% blосk title %}Главная{% endblock %} - Доска объявлений</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <hl>Объявления</hl>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <а href="{% url 'index' %}">Главная</а>
            <а href="{% url 'add' %}">Добавить</а>
            {% for rubric in rubrics %}
            <а href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</а>
            {% endfor %}
        </nav>
        <section>
        {% blосk content %}
        { % endblock % }
        </section>
    </body>
</html>][2]
```

index.html

```
{% extends "layout/basic.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div class="b">
    <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content  }}</p>
    <p><a href='{% url "by_rubric" bb.rubric.pk %}'>{{bb.rubric.name}}</a></p>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I looked at the code, tags and syntax, too - I didn’t find anything. Help, please

Comment: Can you show the `TEMPLATE` settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must correct **{ % endblock % }** to **{% endblock %}** that might be the error. That is in line 21 of your basic.html.
I mean you have put a space between { and %. and I tried this mistake and got the same error. so if you delete the space between { and % you will be okay.